# can I have multiple dns names with one IP address

Tags: networking, ip

Can I have one IP address and many names? 
but one dns name resolves to only one address right?

So I can buy multipe domain name and register all to one ip?

Comment: Kimmy, yes, you can, as many DNS names can resolve to the same IP as you want. But this question is probably best suited for ServerFault (or maybe SuperUser) since it's not really related to programming. It's more of a networking thing.

Comment: @paxdiablo hmm does the other way work as well? many ip for one dns?

Comment: Kimmy, yes, but only one at a time and your DNS provider has to support it. This is the way DNS-based load balancing works, with requests going to one of many different destinations.